# How to verify if node reboot was triggered by the watchdog?

Tags: kernel, watchdog

I have created software watchdog device using command:

`$ sudo modprobe softdog soft_margin=60`

In OS log it is visible that software watchdog was initialized:

`Jul 12 09:49:00 patroni4 kernel: softdog: Software Watchdog Timer: 0.08 initialized. soft_noboot=0 soft_margin=60 sec soft_panic=0 (nowayout=0)`

To trigger node reboot by the watchdog I have executed `echo a | sudo tee /dev/watchdog`.

Node rebooted but in the logs there is no info that reboot was triggered by the watchdog.
If I set option `soft_noboot=1` in the OS log there is message `softdog: Triggered - Reboot ignored`.

Based on the watchdog implementation there should be log message when node reboot was triggered by the watchdog.
https://github.com/spacex/kernel-centos7/blob/master/drivers/watchdog/softdog.c

```
static void watchdog_fire(unsigned long data)
{
    if (soft_noboot)
        pr_crit("Triggered - Reboot ignored\n");
    else if (soft_panic) {
        pr_crit("Initiating panic\n");
        panic("Software Watchdog Timer expired");
    } else {
        pr_crit("Initiating system reboot\n");
        emergency_restart();
        pr_crit("Reboot didn't ?????\n");
    }
}
```

OS: CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
Linux lin1 3.10.0-1160.62.1.el7.x86_64

How can I verify if reboot was triggered by the watchdog?
Why this information is not logged? Can I enable logging somehow?

Thank you for the info

Comment: Do you want to tell a watchdog reboot apart from any other unclean reboot like a power fault? Because the watchdog is supposed to work (even) when the system is otherwise totally stuck, it might not be that easy for it to do something like creating a file. (Those being the main type of permanent storage there is.) It would probably be easier to fix the sequence for an _orderly shutdown_ to record the fact that the system went down on purpose, and then treat any other shutdown as an issue, be it due to a watchdog reset or a power out or something else.

Comment: Yes - I want to distinguish what reboot is related to the watchdog. I am using software watchdog in Patroni cluster configuration. For example watchdog should trigger reboot if Patroni process is suspended for any reason. And reboot is triggered, just I don't see in the logs info that reboot was triggered by the watchdog. Based on the watchdog implementation I would expect `softdog: Initiating system reboot` but not sure why I don't have this info. For `soft_noboot=1` I see `softdog: Triggered - Reboot ignored`. What do you mean by "fix the sequence for an orderly shutdown"?

Comment: The watchdog likely doesn't even attempt to sync writes to the disk or cleanly unmount filesystems. It might need to do its job even doing one of those is impossible. You might have better luck with the logs going over a network. Or a serial port. But even then, there's not much room there between the logging and the  `emergency_restart()` call, and if the latter just resets everything the hard way, any data left in buffers anywhere whould get lost. You could of course use something else than softdog to watch the cluster process, something that could a somewhat cleaner shutdown instead.

Comment: This is Linux Kernel implementation of the software watchdog, so even if I would like I don't know how to redirect logs to go over a network. Probably node is rebooted before logs are flushed to the disk. I assume everything is reset in a hard way as stuck process can sometimes interfere with the clean shutdown and for possible split-brain situation you want system shutdown/restart asap. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: logging over the network is a function of whatever logging software you use (`rsyslog`, `syslog-ng`? Not sure if systemd has something for that). Though syslogd would still need to catch that message from the kernel message buffer and send it out to the socket, before the watchdog resets everything. There looks to be `netconsole` for sending kernel messages over the network directly, I wonder that'd help there: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/netconsole.txt And/or switching the watchdog to `soft_panic` and configuring it to reboot after a timeout on panic.

Comment: (of course, you still wouldn't have a local file to tell if the watchdog triggered, but would have to find that out from some other host that reads the logs over the network)

Comment: I have triggered Watchdog restart with `soft_panic` configuration enabled, and there is no info in the logs that Watchdog initiated reboot. Will check `netconsole`. thx

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your watchdog you can either request it's last log or just create a flag file with current timestamp right before rebooting.

You can always request last boot time from the OS by command `last reboot` or `last reboot -n1`.

Now you just need to compare the two timestamps - if a difference between watchdog's timestamp and boot time is just enough for reboot - the answer is yes.

Comment: I am using Linux kernel software watchdog and I am not sure how can I log or create a flag with current timestamp right before rebooting.
Also I am puzzled why don't I have any info in the logs as `pr_crit` method should log something in any case.

Check my example how I triggered watchdog reboot.

Without any info from the software watchdog side I cannot do comparison with `last reboot` or `last reboot -n1`.